# How to count number of lines and insert that value in the file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have my input file as:

```
aa 12
bb 23 
cc 34
dd 45
```

and so on... This is just the format of the file. My actual file has about 10,000s of lines. I want to get the output as :

```
\data\
 n-grams = 4

 \1-grams:
 aa 12
 bb 23
 cc 34
 dd 45

 \end\
```

I have used this code:

```
 with open("Input.txt") as infile:

    with open("Output.txt","w") as outfile:
        for i,line in enumerate(infile):
            if i==0:
                # 1st line
                count = sum(1 for line in infile)                
                outfile.write("\data\ \n")
                outfile.write("n-grams = " + str(count) + '\n\n')
                outfile.write("\\1-grams:\n")
            elif i==3:
               # 4th line
               pass
            else:
              outfile.write(line)
```

But, this code is inserting

```
\data\
n-grams = 3

\1-grams:
```

It is not printing the rest of the data. And, it is counting only 3 elements line instead of 4.  How can I modify this to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
with open('infile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\\data\\\n')
    f.write('n-grams = {}\n'.format(len(lines)))
    f.write('\\1-grams:\n')
    for l in lines:
        f.write(l)
```

Comment: new_last_line = (lines[-1].rstrip() + "\n\n" + "\end\\")
    lines[-1] = new_last_line // This part can be added to add the \end\ line in the last line of the file.